# Programatically edit back-end data such as category descriptions in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

Can anyone shed any light on how I might programatically edit with PHP the data accessible in the admin such as the category description, product name etc in Magento?

I have scoured Google but am unable to find anything to that effect at all.

I hear of a Magento API that seems to use SOAP, could this be used perhaps? All my code would be local to the Magento installation at any rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is local then load the category model by category id (or any parameter unique to that category) and change the description with

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(categoryid);->setYourvariable('yournewvalue')->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciate the help... Would you know what the call would be for a CMS page or static block?

Comment: i guess it would be the same at the end but putting this to CMS page would be pointless?